# Keep track of current line number in eval

Tags: javascript, angularjs, eval, line-numbers

I'm running some code using eval that will change a `$scope` object called `variables`.

Here's my watcher:

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
  return $scope.variables;
}, function (variables) {
  console.log('changed!');
}, true);
```

Here's the code I'm running (this is just example code; it could be any arbitrary code I can't anticipate):

```
eval('$scope.variables.foo = "bar";\n$scope.variables.bar = "foo";');
```

In this example, the watcher is triggered twice, and gives me the new values. So far so good. What's missing is the information that the first trigger was caused by the first line in the eval call, and the second one on the second line (note the `\n` in the eval call denoting a new line number).

Is there a way to achieve this using Angular or just plain JavaScript? I have looked into tools like https://github.com/stacktracejs/stacktrace.js but they don't seem to do the trick.

Just to be clear, I'm **not** looking for line numbers for when errors are thrown. I need to keep track of which line the eval statement is currently on when the watcher's callback is triggered, so that I can associate that line number with the change that has been made to the object I'm watching.

Comment: Is there _no_ way to get rid of that `eval`? In other words: why do you need to use it?

Comment: I don't think for my use case, no. If you can think of a solution without eval, I'd be happy to hear it, though. I just need some way of executing arbitrary code from a string. (I'm aware that eval is not safe etc. That's not an issue at the moment.)

Comment: I can't think of an alternative if your only requirement is _"Execute arbitrary code from a string."_ Usually, _that requirement_ is the problem.

Comment: No, it's not possible (well, *possible* but difficult). And it's not even `eval` that makes it hard, it's the fact that $watch doesn't provide the information about what change in object triggered it.

Comment: @dfsq What would be the difficult way?

Comment: Manually compare newValue with oldValue in watcher and finding the difference.

Comment: @dfsq I'm not concerned about that. I need the line number.

Comment: I know, what I said is only the first step. But you first need to know what triggered watcher. As I said it's a hard way so not worth doing, as to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split your input string by `\n` and insert new statements keeping track of the line numbers

```js
var s = '$scope.variables.foo = "bar";\n$scope.variables.bar = "foo";\n'
var arr = s.split(/\n/);
var out = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  out.push("console.log('current line: " + i + "');");
  out.push(arr[i]);
}
out = out.join('\n');
console.log(out);
document.write('<pre>' + out + '</pre>');
```

You can replace the `console.log()` by what you want, a call to another function, a debug call...

Comment: Can I just say: Damn that's ugly! But I guess it can work.

Comment: Maybe but in the end it's only string manipulation, nothing else. The OP is ok with eval so messing with the input string is not so shocking :)

Comment: Replacing line breaks with code that indicates the line number is the way to go. Thank you.